# How to add comma between multiple postgres data but not at the end using php?

Tags: php, postgresql

my php code is like this:

```
    <?php 
    require_once 'DBOperations.php';

                    $db = new DBOperations();
                    $data = $db->soilDescription($profile);
    for($j=0; $j<sizeof($data); $j++)
    {

<?php echo $data[$j]['consistence_moist']; ?>, <?php echo $data[$j]['consistence_dry']; ?>, <?php echo $data[$j]['conisitence_wet']; ?> Consistency;
}
```

Here, some postgres data may be null also. so we don't need ',' in null or empty values.
I want output something like this:
Plastic, Sticky Consistency;

But, I am getting output like this:

, , Plastic, Sticky Consistency;

Comment: if you select `consistence_moist||','` instead of `consistence_moist` it will return null, instead of ` ,`

Comment: <?php echo $data[$j]['consistence_moist||','']; ?> is showing error near ','

Comment: no,no - change it in query, look into `$db->soilDescription`

Comment: $query="SELECT array_agg('[' || consistence_moist || ',' || consistence_dry || ',' || conisitence_wet || ']') FROM tbl_soil_profile_2 WHERE profile_no ". $profile." GROUP BY horizon_symbol " (It shows all three values null. But actually, only consistence_dry value is null)